# Timeout connecton between SIM800A and Cloudmqtt

Tags: cloud, mqtt, sim800

I have a problem with a timeout connection when I use SIM800A to subscribe to a topic on cloudmqtt. All is ok when I send the connect and subscribe packet with AT commands, but after 2 minutes the SIM800A disconnects from cloudmqtt and closes the TCP connection. I think the problem is that the TCP connection times out. I want SIM800 to keep its connection to the server in order to subscribe to messages from that server at anytime.

Has anyone had the same problem? How do I solve this problem?

I appreciate your reply.

Comment: There is no code with your post, so this isn't really a question for StackOverflow....might have better luck on Reddit or something.

Comment: Cellular is not a good radio interface for long-lived MQTT connections.  Your carrier might disconnect you if your connections stay up too long.  Its usually better to do an intermittent connect w/polling using something besides MQTT.

Comment: @JDAllen Thanks for your reply. I just use AT command to send connect, publish, subscribe to cloudmqtt. I try change KEEP-ALIVE in  connect packet then timeout-connection changed. So, Can I keep timeout-connection continously by change KEEP-ALIVE value? if can, what is value?